# Events triggering loading content on Facebook's timeline

Tags: facebook, dom-events, htmlunit, nutch, facebook-timeline

I am working on Apache Nutch modification project. We already swapped Nutch's original module with ours built using HtmlUnit. I need to download whole Facebook user site (ex. http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002517096832), which is going to be parsed using our own parser. Unfortunately Facebook is using mechanism called BigPipe (http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919). That's why most of current website is hidden in `<.!-- -->` tags.
Usually when we scroll down Facebook page, new content is being unpacked every time we are about to hit bottom of the page. I have tried to use Javascript that scroll my `htmlPage` (`HtmlPage` object from `HtmlUnit` project), but finally I realized that scrolling is not triggering loading new content on Facebook user site.

How can I check, what event on page triggers loading content on current Facebook page? Maybe I should approach problem from different side, for example try to extract BigPipe "things" on my own? Have you ever did that?

Answer (score 0):

Before dealing to your question … what kind of project are you trying to build there?

Since Apache Nutch is an *open source web-search software*, I think you are trying to build some kind of search engine, that scrapes Facebook user profiles/feeds to get data and make it searchable on some third-party website?

Well, that would be a violoation of [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> I. Features and Functionality
>
> `12.` You must not include data obtained from us in any search engine or directory without our written permission.

So, do you have that written permission?

Comment: Facebook is just an example of website deeply using AJAX and it is the only purpose why I use it. I am not going to use any data that I can get from Facebook. That kind of mechanisms are used often at other websites, for example: http://imgur.com/gallery